# form built dynamically with php, not submitting

Tags: php, forms

On one of my wordpress admin pages, I am building a form to add new mailers.

I have it checking the templates mysql table and building the list of available templates, then also giving it the option to add a new template.

for some reason, the form is not submitting. When I use chrome's console, I see it says syntax error unexpected } but I don't see a } anywhere in the HTML output on the page.

Here is my php that builds the form:

```
    <form action="http://somedomain.com/new-mailer" method="GET" name="form1"><hidden name="action" value="createANewMailer"><hidden name="then" value="customize"><?php
        $results = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM `mailerTemplateFiles` where `u` = '1'"));
        $_MenuItem = "<select name=\"template\" required=\"1\" size=\"1\" autofocus>";
        foreach ($results as $res) {
            $_optv = $res->mtid;
            $_optl = $res->layoutname;
            $_MenuItem .= "<option value=\"$_optv\">" . $_optl . "</option>\n";
        }
        $_MenuItem .= "<option value=\"addNew\">Add New Template</option>";
        $_MenuItem .= "</select>";
        echo $_MenuItem;
    ?><input type="button" onclick="document.getElementById("form1").submit();" value="Continue"></form>
```

I have tried to just let it submit naturally by clicking the button, no onclick, but it did not work, so I added the onclick way to submit it. that does not work either.

Here is the HTML output it generates:

```
<form action="http://somedomain.com/new-mailer" method="GET" name="form1"><hidden name="action" value="createANewMailer"><hidden name="then" value="customize"><select name="template" required="1" size="1" autofocus><option value="addNew">Add New Template</option></select><input type="button" onclick="document.getElementById("form1").submit();" value="Continue"></form>
```

I don't see why it won't work.

-Rich

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form does not contain an ID. You need to replace `name="form1"` with `id="form1"`.

This is because your javascript says,

```
onclick="document.getElementById("form1").submit();"
```

which returns False, because there is no form with the ID "form1".